# How close are tracks 1 and 2 in the Eindhoven train station?

Tags: transit, train-stations, eindhoven

How close is track 1 to track 2 at Eindhoven train station?

Comment: You're probably wondering because you want to change trains, and the times of the 2 trains leaving match up exactly? IIRC, that's intentional - the two trains synchronize there. If one is slightly late, it will wait for the other.

Comment: Since you already have answers here, I’ll just say the 9292 app (Android/iOS) is extremely helpful for planning routes in the Netherlands if you don’t know about the app already.

Answer (score 14):

https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/51.44309/5.48082

They are on opposing sides of the same platform.

Answer (score 3):

I was in Eindhoven for a month last year. As asdfex said, they are on opposing sides of the same platform. You shouldn't have any trouble going from one to the other.